# Toggle properties of anchor and image elements via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I currently have a single web page that contains two elements:

- **image** (wrapped in anchor, loads URL in iframe)
- **iframe** (loads `themes.html` by default)

The image, on-click, toggles/switches the iframe between `themes.html` and `styles.html`, as well as the image source. However, despite the numerous tutorials and forum posts I have read online, I cannot get it to work.

How would I go about having the image toggle when clicked, as well as toggling the source of the iframe between the two HTML files?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Manager</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" />
</head>

<body>

    <div class="switch">
        <a href="styles.html" target="switchframe" id="toggleURL" onclick="toggleURL();">
        <img src="images/segment-theme.png" id="toggleImage" onclick="toggleImage();"/></a>

        <iframe id="frame" name="switchframe" src="themes.html"></iframe>
    </div>

    <script>
        function toggleImage() {
            var img1 = "images/segment-theme.png";
            var img2 = "images/segment-style.png";
            var imgElement = document.getElementById('toggleImage');
            imgElement.src = (imgElement.src === img1)? img2 : img1;
        }

        function toggleURL() {
            var url1 = "themes.html"
            var url2 = "styles.html"
            var urlElement = document.getElementById('toggleURL');
            urlElement.href = (urlElement.href === url1)? url2 : url1;
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:** I figure I could maybe have it just toggle the iframe's `src` property directly, but if I can't even get the image's `src` to toggle to begin with, I fear I won't be able to get that working either.

**EDIT 2:** I can get it to load `styles.html` in the iframe with the code below; however, I cannot get it to toggle back to `themes.html`:

```
function toggleURL() {
    var url1 = "themes.html"
    var url2 = "styles.html"
    var urlElement = document.getElementById('frame');
    urlElement.src = (urlElement.src === url1)? url2 : url1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're having issues because you're using `element.attribute` instead of `element.getAttribute('attribute-name')`.

Since image.src will return the absolute path `www.domain.com/path/to/image.png` where getAttribute returns the value specified in the element.

Also you need only one event handler for your case.

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>Manager</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="switch">
        <a href="styles.html" id="toggleURL" onclick="toggle(event);">
            <img src="images/segment-theme.png" id="toggleImage" />
        </a>

        <iframe id="frame" src="themes.html"></iframe>
    </div>

    <script>
        function toggle(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var img1 = "images/segment-theme.png";
            var img2 = "images/segment-style.png";
            var imgElement = document.getElementById('toggleImage');
            var src = imgElement.getAttribute('src');
            imgElement.setAttribute('src', (src === img1) ? img2 : img1)

            var url1 = "themes.html"
            var url2 = "styles.html"
            var urlElement = document.getElementById('toggleURL');
            var href = urlElement.getAttribute('href');
            document.getElementById('frame').setAttribute('src', href)
            urlElement.setAttribute('href', (href === url1) ? url2 : url1)
        }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```